# Is there a way to make google chrome (running under ubuntu) open fullscreen by default?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome

Is there a way to make google chrome open fullscreen by default? Also, is there a hotkey to make it fullscreen?

Answer (score 3):

From the [source file](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) itself.

```
// Start the browser maximized, regardless of any previous settings.
const char kStartMaximized[]                = "start-maximized";
```

Try `--start-maximized`?

The [bug filed](http://codereview.chromium.org/399106) regarding F11 fullscreen not working with GTK is marked fixed, and checked in 5 weeks ago.  Not sure how old your version of Chrome is, or whether you're using trunk builds.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's in there yet.

I [checked the keyboard shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95743) for Google Chrome and while there is one for Windows, there isn't one for Linux...

There is [a feature request for the so called 'kiosk mode'](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145) on Google Code

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Compiz's Window Rules to make apps start Maximized. I haven't done with Chrome specifically, but I'd say it's very likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can start chromium on Ubuntu 11.04 in kiosk mode (fullscreen) with

```
chromium-browser --kiosk http://www.google.com
```

It also has a hotkey mapped to F11